# Лицензирование Tomcat/MySQL/JRE на виртуальный машине CentOS

Tags: java, tomcat

Есть java-приложение, написанное для последующего деплоя в Tomcat. Приложение работает, однако пользователю нужно выполнить кучу действий на чистой машине, прежде, чем удастся задеплоить его серверную часть. А именно:

1. Поставить JRE
2. Поставить Tomcat
3. Поставить MySQL
4. Наконец-таки задеплоить приложение

Есть решение - завернуть всё в образ виртуальной машины (тот же CentOS) и отдать пользователю - для общения с приложением у него отдельный "тонкий клиент".
Далее раздавать пользователям уже этот образ в качестве триальной версии - пусть пробуют. И вот он вопрос - как же быть с лицензированием JRE, Tomcat, MySQL. Порыскав в интернете (может и плохо рыскал), я так и не понял, можно ли включить их в конечный образ виртуальной машины, которая и будет триальной версией продукта.
Отсюда вопрос: кто что может подсказать касательно тонкостей лицензирования?

Comment: Плохой подход. Это лишает пользователя использовать имеющуюся инфраструктуру и ограничивает возможности масштабирования приложения.

Comment: Спасибо, принял во внимание. Это решение мне понравилось тем, что от пользователя потребуется минимум действий для "установки" приложения.